# Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView/LayoutManager

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, mono

I am trying to debug my Xamarin project. Framework and all packages are up to date. In iOS it works, but in Android NOT. How can I solve this problem:

```
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView/LayoutManager::n_OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo_Landroidx_recyclerview_widget_RecyclerView_Recycler_Landroidx_recyclerview_widget_RecyclerView_State_Landroidx_core_view_accessibility_AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat_(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)' in assembly: 'Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve AndroidX.Core.View.Accessibiity.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()
```

Comment: Here is a similar issue that maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132157/mono-linker-markexception-error-processing-method-system-void-plugin-localnot

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I encountered this same problem after updating Visual Studio to 16.9.2 and updating the Android SDK.

The simple solution was to update the '**Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView**' Nuget package in the package manager. I Updated to the latest version (v1.1.0.8).

Comment: Thank you for your hint.
My solution was to install 'Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView' in the first place.

Comment: Same here.  I didn't have that package installed.  Installed it and it fixed the error.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks!

Comment: Off course for me it doesn't work!!! Never ever works in Xamarin...

Comment: @user1034912 perhaps you need one of the other packages explicitly installed per https://stackoverflow.com/a/67092611/1399272 - `Xamarin.AndroidX.Core`,
`Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView`,
`Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference`,
`Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 19):

Same problem but i did not have 'Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView' installed.

Solution: install in android project 'Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView' and all work fine

Comment: This is worked for me, I have also updated all the nugget packages in the solution.

Comment: it worked for me also

Comment: This was my case and also worked for me +1

Comment: This worked for me, more or less. I had to install an earlier version of Xamarin.Androidx.RecyclerView, rather than the latest stable

Answer (score 8):

Zee's answer is correct.
here is the explanation which can solve other similar issues.
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/283

> jpobst commented on 1 Mar When resolving transitive dependencies,
> NuGet unfortunately picks the lowest dependency that meets the
> criteria. This means that fixes made to transitive dependencies often
> don't get picked up.
>
> In this case the issue is the namespace misspelling
> (AndroidX.Core.View.Accessibiity) was corrected, however one (or more)
> of the packages that uses types from that namespace are not being
> updated.
>
> You will need to make sure you are using the latest versions of these
> packages, which may require adding an explicit package reference to
> them:
>
> Xamarin.AndroidX.Core 
> Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView 
> Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference 
> Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView

Comment: this one worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this error. In my case, it was finally solved by removing the Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4 NuGet, which was not needed anyway. I think the  auto AndroidX migration put it in.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't have to install any NuGet packages explicitly. I did remove Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat as it wasn't needed anymore, but what I think the real fix is: update Xamarin.Forms to be newer, greater than 5.0.0.2012.

That pulls in all sorts of newer versions of the AndroidX dependencies which seemed to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the problem was with VS 16.9.3 and the release build, and the solution was to remove the dependency on `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources`.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue occurred for me today after I updated all my `nuget` packages, the issue was resolved when I cleaned and rebuilt the solution.

Comment: ironically, the same worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem started when I upgraded to  Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging v 121.1.0 - reverting to v121.0.1 resolved the problem - at least temporarily

Comment: I agree it's just a neverendling endless problems with Xamarin... and as usual none of the solutions here work

Answer (score 0):

My solution is installing: Xamarin.Google.Android.Material via Nuget

Answer (score 0):

Update Visual Studio to the latest version and remove the Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView nugget if you have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this probles just updating the Android SDK version in: **Android Project** > **Properties** > **Aplication** > **Compile Using Android Version** and updating all the Xamarin dependendies with Nuget Manager. My last Android version was **11(S)** and now is **12(R)**.

I hope this can help someone!

Answer (score 0):

When resolving transitive dependencies, NuGet, unfortunately, picks the lowest dependency that meets the criteria. This means that fixes made to transitive dependencies often don't get picked up.

In this case, the issue is the namespace misspelling (AndroidX.Core.View.Accessibiity) was [corrected](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/pull/238), however, one (or more) of the packages that use types from that namespace are not being updated.

I solved this problem just by adding a few Nugets - `Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference` and `Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Preference.V14`

Full list of versions:

```
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.Biometric" Version="1.1.0.6" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView" Version="1.0.0.11" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout" Version="2.1.1.2"  />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core" Version="1.6.0.3" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.ExifInterface" Version="1.3.3.2" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Preference.V14" Version="1.0.0.10" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4" Version="1.0.0.10" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData" Version="2.3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration" Version="1.0.8" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.Media" Version="1.4.3" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference" Version="1.1.1.11" />
<PackageReference Update="Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView" Version="1.2.1.3" />
```

I hope this can help someone!