# AzureDevops Pipeline Generate APK: Error XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.MarkException

Tags: azure, azure-devops, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm encountering this error when my pipeline script for generating an apk runs(It builds and runs fine in Visual Studio 2022):

> ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(660,5):
> Error XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method:
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Sharpnado.HorizontalListView.Services.PageResult`1>
> Sharpnado.HorizontalListView.Paging.Paginator`1::LoadPage(System.Int32,System.Boolean)' in assembly: 'Sharpnado.HorizontalListView.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!0>
> Sharpnado.Tasks.TaskMonitor`1<Sharpnado.HorizontalListView.Services.PageResult`1>::get_Task()

My yml script:

```
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019' # For Mac, use 'macOS-10.13'

variables:
  - group: 'AndroidAppVariables'
  - name: 'buildConfiguration'
    value: 'Release'
  - name: 'outputDirectory'
    value: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'
  - name: 'NugetVersion'
    value: 5.8.0

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet $(NugetVersion)'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: $(NugetVersion)

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: 'src\AndroidApp.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '/a3sb3q3s-ab12-2020-0202-0202020202'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: 'src\AndroidApp.Android\AndroidApp.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    jdkVersionOption: 1.11
    createAppPackage: true
    msbuildVersionOption: latest
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Note that Sharpnado.HorizontalListView is not part of my dependencies at all(maybe in the past)
2. Removed `<GenerateSerializationAssembles>Auto</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>` from Android.csproj file
3. Changing the project file path from \ to /
4. Re-installing of some nuget packages
5. Linking properties is set to **None**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some similar errors in StackOverflow that happened in their Visual Studio(when building in release configuration mode), I also encountered that issue in VS2022. Like what others did in this problem, I also have to install Sharpnado.HorizontalListView 1.8.2 even though the app is not using anymore, as we wanted to keep the changes to a minimum (because we are also migrating to .Net MAUI, while doing that just have to make sure current Xamarin project is still maintained): [Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView/LayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670334/mono-linker-markexception-error-processing-method-system-void-androidx-recycl)

and then it worked also for the pipeline, without changing anything in the script.